# How to resolve 'Vec<Peekable<dyn Iterator<Item = T>>> doesn't have a size known at compile-time'?

Tags: rust

I'm working on a Cartesian power implementation for iterators. I'm running into a snag where I don't seem able to store a vector of peekable copies of the iterator I'm passed. No matter how much I finagle with boxes and pointers, it doesn't work due to `Vec<Peekable<dyn Iterator<Item = T>>>` not having a known size at compile time.

Any ideas for how to make this size be known at compile time? I really just need to be store a pointer to the vector, right? There's no reason it can't be created on the heap, is there?

Here's what I have so far (ignore the next() implementation, that was just to test to see if I could store the iterator and correctly use it's next function):

```
mod cartesian_power {
    use core::iter::Peekable;

    pub struct CartesianPower<T> {
        prototype: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = T>>,
        iters: Vec<Peekable<dyn Iterator<Item = T>>>,
    }

    impl<T> CartesianPower<T> {
        pub fn new<I>(vals: I, power: usize) -> CartesianPower<T>
        where
            I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
            I: Clone,
            <I as IntoIterator>::IntoIter: 'static,
        {
            let iters = Vec::with_capacity(power);
            for _ in 0..power {
                iters.push(vals.clone().into_iter().peekable());
            }
            Self {
                prototype: Box::new(vals.into_iter()),
                iters: iters,
            }
        }

    }

    impl<T> Iterator for CartesianPower<T> {
        type Item = T;
        fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
            self.prototype.next()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store a `Vec<dyn Trait>` (or `Vec<Peekable<dyn Trait>>`) directly, you have to use an indirection as each element can have a different size: `Vec<Box<Peekable<dyn Iterator<Item = T>>>>`.

However, since all iterators in your case are the same, you can use generics and avoid the performance hit of `Box` and dynamic dispatch:

```rust
pub struct CartesianPower<I: Iterator> {
    prototype: I,
    iters: Vec<Peekable<I>>,
}

impl<Iter: Iterator> CartesianPower<Iter> {
    pub fn new<I>(vals: I, power: usize) -> CartesianPower<Iter>
    where
        I: IntoIterator<IntoIter = Iter>,
        I: Clone,
        <I as IntoIterator>::IntoIter: 'static,
    {
        let mut iters = Vec::with_capacity(power);
        for _ in 0..power {
            iters.push(vals.clone().into_iter().peekable());
        }
        Self {
            prototype: vals.into_iter(),
            iters: iters,
        }
    }

}

impl<I: Iterator> Iterator for CartesianPower<I> {
    type Item = I::Item;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<I::Item> {
        self.prototype.next()
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoiding boxing is the way to go. FWIW, OP, here is what boxing looks like: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=37db374cd6c4cea52f6902ff85c17a3b).

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I think I tried making the Cartesian power's generic type be the iterator instead of the inner type at some point, but kept stumbling on the extra steps required to do so (`Iter` instead of `I` for the impl block, how to specify it was of type Iterator, as well as how to specify the inner type when returning next, etc...) All of which you showed me how to do. Thanks!